# Why is WLP installUtility not able obtain assets from feature repo?

Tags: docker, dockerfile, openshift, websphere-liberty

I am running docker build with following Dockerfile, with main idea to use feature repo as described https://github.com/WASdev/ci.docker#installing-liberty-features-from-local-repository-19008:

```docker
    FROM websphere-liberty-kernel-ubi-min:19.0.0.9
    COPY usr/ /opt/ibm/wlp/usr/
    USER root
    ARG FEATURE_REPO_URL=http://xyz.openshift.local/19.0.0.9/repo.zip
    ARG VERBOSE=true
    RUN configure.sh
    RUN  chown -R 1001:0 /tmp \
      && chmod -R g+rw /tmp \
      && chown -R 1001:0 /opt/ibm/wlp/output \
      && chmod -R g+rw /opt/ibm/wlp/output \
      && chown -R 1001:0 /opt/ibm/wlp/usr/servers/defaultServer \
      && chmod -R g+rw /opt/ibm/wlp/usr/servers/defaultServer \
      && chown -R 1001:0 /opt/ibm/wlp/usr/shared/resources \
      && chmod -R g+rw /opt/ibm/wlp/usr/shared/resources
    USER 1001
```

Docker build output shows that repo.zip is downloaded and missing features are detected:

```
+ '[' http://xyz.openshift.local/19.0.0.9/repo.zip ']'
+ curl -k --fail http://xyz.openshift.local/19.0.0.9/repo.zip % Total % Received % Xferd Average Speed Time Time Time Current Dload Upload Total Spent Left Speed 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 0 14 311M 14 44.8M 0 0 55.0M 0 0:00:05 --:--:-- 0:00:05 54.9M 31 311M 31 99.4M 0 0 54.8M 0 0:00:05 0:00:01 0:00:04 54.7M 49 311M 49 152M 0 0 54.2M 0 0:00:05 0:00:02 0:00:03 54.2M 66 311M 66 207M 0 0 54.4M 0 0:00:05 0:00:03 0:00:02 54.4M 83 311M 83 260M 0 0 54.0M 0 0:00:05 0:00:04 0:00:01 54.0M 99 311M 99 310M 0 0 53.4M 0 0:00:05 0:00:05 --:--:-- 53.1M100 311M 100 311M 0 0 53.4M 0 0:00:05 0:00:05 --:--:-- 52.7M
+ installUtility install --acceptLicense defaultServer --from=/tmp/repo.zip
Checking for missing features required by the server ...
The server requires the following additional features: mpconfig-1.3 transportsecurity-1.0 cdi-2.0 mpopenapi-1.0 jaxws-2.2 jsonp-1.1 jpa-2.2 mprestclient-1.3 mphealth-2.1 wssecurity-1.1 jaxrs-2.1. Installing features from the repository ...
Successfully connected to the configured repository.
```

but then installation of all features fails:

```
Preparing assets for installation. This process might take several minutes to complete.
CWWKF1259E: Unable to obtain the following assets: mpconfig-1.3 transportsecurity-1.0 cdi-2.0 mpopenapi-1.0 jaxws-2.2 jsonp-1.1 jpa-2.2 mprestclient-1.3 mphealth-2.1 wssecurity-1.1 jaxrs-2.1. Ensure that the specified assets are valid. To find the IDs of applicable assets, run the installUtility find command.
```

I have taken a look in downloaded repo.zip and I can find following file (that should match one of the missing features):
[image: mpconfig-1.3 is here]

So, what is the reason for the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using different image (ibmcom/websphere-liberty:*some21.0.0.3version*) and pointing FEATURE_REPO_URL to place where 21.0.0.3 repo is hosted works.

So whoever prepared 19.0.0.3 image for me and said which feature repo to use, pointed me to some incompatible artefacts.

What is interesting, when I combined different versions of image vs repo, configure.sh was nicely verbose (it explained there is incompatibility), but this error `CWWKF1259E: Unable to obtain the following assets` is really unhelpful.